# Send messages with my Raspberry pi

Tags: curl, raspberry-pi

I use a API with web interface for send message with my raspberry for do that I used the command line `"curl"` but when I write

```
curl -g http://sms/RaspiSMS/smsAPI/?email=XXX@XXX.fr\&password=XXXXX\&numbers=06XXXXXXXX\&contacts=toto\&groups[]=groupe\&groups[]=test\&text=TestMultiGroups"
```

Only the numbers fields receive the message. I don't now if the problem is with my `api` or the `curl`...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by 'Only the numbers fields receive the message' ?

Comment: Thank you very much @pinegulf

Comment: I create some groups with my api and i would like to send message to few personne without the necessity to resign all the numbers of my groups but only 06XXXXXXXX receive the message

Comment: @udit7395 If I use the web interface, it works

Comment: Your double quotes are not balanced.

Comment: @MarkSetchell It was a mistake, in this case quotes or not the text will be sent but thank for our comment